# Getting error when trying to join one to many in async sqlalchemy and fastapi?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

Im trying to build an api endpoint for advanced filtering. I found the package '[fastapi-filter](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-filter/)' are very useful for this purpose.

the below code using async and postgress connection:

```
DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:********$@localhost:5433/dbname"

engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=True, future=True)

async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async_session = sessionmaker(
        engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False
    )
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
```

running to following code:

```
@router.get("/testing", response_model=List[WebsiteOut], response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def all_websites(
        user_filter: WebsiteFilter = FilterDepends(WebsiteFilter),
        session: Session = Depends(get_session)
):
    query = select(Websites)
    query = query.distinct()
    query = query.join(Websites.website_services)
    query = query.options(contains_eager(Websites.website_services))
    query = query.filter(WebsiteServices.disabled == False)

    query = user_filter.filter(query)
    query = user_filter.sort(query)

    result = await session.execute(query)

    return result.scalars().all()
```

throw the following error:

```
raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: The unique() method must be invoked on this Result, as it contains results that include joined eager loads against collections
```

When i'm trying none async connection:

```
DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:********$@localhost:5433/dbname"

engine_db = create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL, echo=True, future=True
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine_db)

def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

the following code execute successfully:

```
@router.get("/test", response_model=List[WebsiteOut], response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def all_websites(
        user_filter: WebsiteFilter = FilterDepends(WebsiteFilter),
        db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
    query = db.query(Websites)

    query = query.distinct()
    query = query.join(Websites.website_services)
    query = query.options(contains_eager(Websites.website_services))
    query = query.filter(WebsiteServices.disabled == False)

    query = user_filter.filter(query)
    query = user_filter.sort(query)

    result = query.all()

    return result
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "url": "https://www.******.com",
        "tat": 10,
        "website_services": [
            {
                "service_name": "cbd",
                "service_cost": 250,
                "website_id": 26
            },
            {
                "service_name": "guest_post",
                "service_cost": 100,
                "website_id": 26
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.*************.com",
        "tat": 10,
        "website_services": [
            {
                "service_name": "guest_post",
                "service_cost": 150,
                "website_id": 13
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm scretching my head to find the issue. hope you will help me find the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem. all I needed to do is to return
`result.scalars().unique().all()`

here is the final code:

```
@router.get("/testing", response_model=List[WebsiteOut], response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def all_websites(
        user_filter: WebsiteFilter = FilterDepends(WebsiteFilter),
        session: Session = Depends(get_session)
):
    query = select(Websites)
    query = query.distinct()
    query = query.join(Websites.website_services)
    query = query.options(contains_eager(Websites.website_services))
    query = query.filter(WebsiteServices.disabled == False)

    query = user_filter.filter(query)
    query = user_filter.sort(query)

    result = await session.execute(query)

    return result.scalars().unique().all()
```

Comment: thanks man, saved me. The SQLalchemy documentation is complete trash and this is nowhere mentioned, literally spent hours looking for this >.>